# Java Finding String regex

Tags: java, regex

I tried to get  these date *22-APR-16 11.00.00.000000* and *22-APR-16 10.30.00.000000*.
My codes are there but it cant find ,how can I do?

```
String pattern = "(Başlangıç Tarihi:\\s+)([0-9/:]+\\s+[0-9:]+)(.*)\\s+(Bitiş Tarihi:\\s+)([0-9/:]+\\s+[0-9:]+)(.*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

String text = "Başlangıç Tarihi:   22-APR-16 11.00.00.000000 AM  Bitiş Tarihi:   22-APR-16 10.30.00.000000 PM";
Matcher m = r.matcher(text);

if(m.find())
{
    String startDate = m.group(2);
    String endDate = m.group(5);

    System.out.println("Start Date : " + startDate);
    System.out.println("End Date : " + endDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KISS

```
String pattern = "(Başlangıç Tarihi:\\s+)(\\d+-[A-Za-z]+-\\d+\\s[\\d.]+)(.*)\\s+(Bitiş Tarihi:\\s+)(\\d+-[A-Za-z]+-\\d+\\s[\\d.]+)";
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/LU08Tq)**

Moreover, you can just use

```
(\\d+-[A-Za-z]+-\\d+\\s[\\d.]+)
```

and find all the matches using loop and store it an array or arraylist. Every even element will be start date and odd element will be end date